# failing to define an array key with a value of false

Tags: php, boolean

So I have a multi-dim array. I'm defining a few array keys with boolean as values:

```
$geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['country']=true;
$geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['country_short']=true;
$geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']=false;
$geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city_short']=false;
```

Now I do a `print_r()` on that, and this is the result:

```
( [country] => 1 [country_short] => 1 [city] => [city_short] => )
```

Now correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `false==0`?

I try to do a quick check on the value (for booleans):

```
if($geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']==boolean){
//this returns false...
}
```

The condition above returns `false` with `['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']` but `true` with `['hostip']['geoTypes']['country']`. The only difference between the two is that `city` has the value of `false` and `country` has the value of `true`.

When I define the value as `0` instead of `false` - all works well...

I have a feeling there is something I have embarrassingly missed, which is resulting to this misunderstanding.

Anyone care to explain? - (Why `false!=0`?)

Comment: @ccKep That does return the expected result, but the if condition I mentioned still returns false, telling me the value is not a boolean, when it clearly is.

Comment: Your if is comparing true/false to "boolean" - obviously it returns false. Maybe you want to compare `gettype(...) == "boolean"`? Either that or replace it with what you actually want to test (eg `true` or `false`)

Comment: What do you mean by using 'boolean' in this line? if($geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']==boolean){

Comment: @itsmeee `boolean==true OR false`. so if the value of `$geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']` is true or false..

Comment: @ccKep so why does the condition return true when I compare it with a value of `true`?

Comment: I've explained in detail in my answer below. You can't simply compare to `boolean`, compare either to `true` or `false`.

Comment: wait, if you run the code like this - using "boolean" itself - it's not a type, it's just an underfined constant "boolean" that is being converted to a string 'boolean', which of course does not equal false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing your variable (that contains `(bool) true` / `(bool) false`) to `boolean`. The Simple literal `boolean` is not defined, PHP handles it as a string.

`if($geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']==boolean)`

therefore becomes

`if($geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']=="boolean")`

The `==` operator compares those to after type-juggling. `"boolean"` is a non-empty string and gets treated as `(bool) true`. So your comparisions boil down to `(bool) true == (bool) true` which returns `true` and `(bool) false == (bool) true` which returns `false` ofcourse.

Comment: Fair enough. Just found the `is_bool()` too. Thanks.

Comment: The explicit question was "why is false != 0", which this doesn't answer.  But, hey, if it solved your problem - good on ya!

Comment: Maybe simply because `false == 0`. (Note that we're using a lose comparision operator here). So the basic answer here is 'It's not.'.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that the issue is with the printing via print_r and not the setting.  The following line will output bool(false)

```
var_dump( $geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']);
```

also `var_dump( $geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city'] == false);` will output bool(true)

and `var_dump( $geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city'] == 0);` will output bool(true)

Slightly off-topic:
Generally, it's a good idea to avoid treating boolean values to integers to make the code more readable, especially for developers who use multiple languages.

Comment: Yup. But when I run that if statement on it, it returns false - which is telling me the value is not a bool.

Comment: you're comparing $geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']==boolean.  Try using the following in the if statement instead:  (is_bool($geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes']['city']));

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($geo_entries['hostip']['geoTypes'] as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ' is ' . (is_bool($value) ? 'boolean' : 'not boolean') . '<br />'; 
}
```

outputs:

```
country is boolean
country_short is boolean
city is boolean
city_short is boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you do type comparison in PHP. If you want to check whether a variable `$foo` is a boolean, you can do this:

```
if (is_bool($foo))
{
    // ...
}
```

What your example is in fact doing is interpreting `boolean` as a string and checking whether it should be considered `true` when interpreted as a boolean value. This will generate an E_NOTICE message (which may or may not be visible depending on your error reporting level).

Answer (score 0):

False is not equal to 0 because the type of the variable you're checking is boolean.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

The doc says the following values are false:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- ...

This does NOT say that boolean FALSE == integer 0.

Comment: `echo assert(false == 0);` wants a word with you. We're talking lose comparisions here. In other words: `false == 0`, `false !== 0`.

Comment: True enough.  But, line of code about which he complained "isn't boolean == 0?" wasn't doing comparison, but printing the values in the array.  It seemed to me he was confused as to why didn't the print_r give back 0 for [city] and [city_short].  That implied to me that he expects integers and booleans to be universally interchangeable, which they're not.

Comment: Indeed they're not, I told him in the top comment to use `var_dump()` checking his actual values. The question title implied to me that he thought he couldn't define array values as (bool)false, which he can. He just didn't know how to look at it - atleast that was my impression. My complete answer then followed from the other comments there.

Comment: @ccKep That should be "loose" comparison, not "lose" (I saw you spell it that way twice, so I thought it was worth pointing out).